# AJAX Posting in JQuery: Is there a Record Limit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I ran into a problem when collecting information from a Javascript DataTable to post to an MVC (Core) Controller.

I was able to replicate the problem and found that when I run less than 205 records, it works perfectly.  When I run 205 or more, it immediately gives me a 500 Internal Error Message.  However, it's not triggering anything in Visual Studio, nor is it leaving a log entry on my Windows machine, like other .net errors.  If anybody has any insight into what is going on, I would REALLY appreciate it!

Thanks!

```
for (i = 0; i < 205; i++) {
            creditCardCharge = {
                'customerID': "BOB" + i,
                'amount': i,
                'description': "",
                'ccRowID': 1,
                'datePosted': d.toDateString()
            }
            records.push(creditCardCharge)
        }
        var data = { chargesInfo: records, logEntry: "via Dues Report", reportType: $("ddlTypeOfReport").val() };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TOPSECRETLOCATION",
            data: { chargesInfo: records, logEntry: "via Dues Report", reportType: $("ddlTypeOfReport").val()},
            success: function (response) {
                var r = response;
                $.each(r.list, function (i, v) {
                    if (r.list[i].result == true) {
                        $('#' + r.list[i].customerID + ' td:nth-child(2)').append("<br /><span style='color:green'>" + r.list[i].message + "</span>");
                    } else {
                        $('#' + r.list[i].customerID + ' td:nth-child(2)').append("<br /><span style='color:red'>" + r.list[i].message + "</span>");
                    }
                });
                EnableScreen();
                DeselectAllCheckboxes();
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alertify.error(response);
                EnableScreen();
                DeselectAllCheckboxes();
            }
        });
```

Comment: A 500 is server side issue, not client side. Limits depend on a lot of factors and are more server load related than client side. Hard to believe you don't get any server side logs when 500 status is returned. It's the server that returns that status

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can continue to find where this limit is and how to deal with it?  I'm sending no more than 1/2 a MB of information.  It shouldn't be overloading anything. Concerning the logs... nothing on server or production.  Very strange.

Comment: I'm putting together the information and sending it in one shot.

Comment: Oops right. Misread the poorly formatted code and was thinking ajax was inside the loop. Still need to resolve issue server side. `500` is server side error

Comment: I was able to get something from my local production finally:
InvalidDataException: Form value count limit 1024 exceeded.

Comment: Is the JSON size still a thing in Core? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could send as JSON instead of form encoded which is $.ajax default

Comment: I found that this helped (in Startup.cs):


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

{

    services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.ValueCountLimit = 10000);

    services.AddMvc();

}

Comment: I put the dataType to json, and I'm now getting:

InvalidDataException: Form key or value length limit 2048 exceeded.

Comment: I almost never work with .NET. That error is probably easily searched on web and on this site

Answer (score 0):

500 (Internal Server Error) happens when your Ajax call response with exceeded amount of JSON data. Simple solution for this as below.

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```